# How I can filter the duplicate data by date from controller to view Using Sql Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using SQL query

[image: This is my description on the sql server I want to apply to the program with little change]

**I have tried this code but failed**

This is the controller code

```
        public ActionResult xternal(string Datecall)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string str = "Data Source=MAHGOUBND4;Initial Catalog=CTC_Mahgoub;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ah987987987;";
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(str))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" SELECT EmployeeName, COUNT(EmployeeName) as 'Duplecated'  FROM [dbo].[cs] WHERE Datecall LIKE '%" +Datecall.Tostring()+ "%' GROUP BY EmployeeName HAVING COUNT(EmployeeName) > 1; "))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = cn;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(dt);
        }
```

this is my view code

I have problem in my code I want to compensate for the datatable value Datecall in text Datecall how i can do it

This is the view code

```
@using System.Data
@model DataTable

<input type="text" name="date" id="Datecall" placeholder="Date" required="" />

<input type="button" id="btnsearch" name="btnsearch" value="Chart" style="color:green" />

<table cellpadding="5" id="employeeTable" cellspacing="5" border="1">
    <tr style="background-color:aliceblue">
        <th>EmployeeName</th>
        <th>Duplecated</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (DataRow dr in Model.Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@dr["EmployeeName"]</td>
            <td>@dr["Duplecated"]</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: any body help me please

Comment: Your input name must match the Action parameter like: `<input type="text" name="Datecall" id="Datecall" placeholder="Date" required="" />`

Comment: how i can fixed this problem

Comment: Wrap your inputs in a form tag like: `@using (Html.BeginForm()) { <input type="text" name="Datecall" id="Datecall" placeholder="Date" required="" />
<input type="submit" id="btnsearch" name="btnsearch" value="Chart" style="color:green" /> }` to pass data to Controller, note that the `type` of second `input` is `submit`.